# WPF KeyBinding disable and let bubble up keyboard shortcut

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I am working on a project which uses MVVM, KeyBinding and ICommand.

I have, on the same window, multiple nested Views (UserControls) and many of them uses the same KeyBinding "Ctrl+S" to run a `SaveCommand`.

The ViewModel associated with the View, has a `IsSaveCommandAvailable` property, that can tell if the `SaveCommand` is available in that ViewModel.

In my case, only the "root" View has to be able to launch the `SaveCommand` by hitting Ctrl+S, the nested ones have to ignore the key hit and let it bubble up to the root View, that does all the Save stuff.

I googled for finding a solution, and only found that I can use `ICommand.CanExecute` to return false and avoid the KeyBinding to run.

But this solution does not fit my needs, because if I hit Ctrl+S on a child View, its `SaveCommand` CanExecute returns false, and the key hit is lost.

Is there a way to bubble up the key hit until a KeyBinding can be run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is to use a `IValueConverter` on the `Key` property of KeyBinding, converting a boolean value to the key passed as CommandParameter, and, if the value is `false`, return `Key.None`:

```
public class BooleanToKeyConverter : IValueConverter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Key to use when the value is false
    /// </summary>
    public Key FalseKey { get; set; } = Key.None;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool flag && flag && parameter != null && parameter != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            if (parameter is Key key)
            {
                return key;
            }
            else if (Enum.TryParse<Key>(parameter.ToString(), out var parsedKey))
            {
                return parsedKey;
            }
        }
        return this.FalseKey;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

In a resource file (eg: App.xaml):

```
<conv:BooleanToKeyConverter x:Key="boolToKey"/>
```

where "conv" is your local namespace.

Then, in KeyBindings:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" 
    Key="{Binding Path=IsSaveCommandAvailable, Converter={StaticResource boolToKey}, ConverterParameter=S}" 
    Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
```

Comment: sooo whats the point of posting this here if you have the response already?
looking for a better way?

Comment: @DenisSchaf, Stack Overflow fully supports self-answering questions.  We exist in order to help others.  This question (and answer) will now hopefully help someone in the future encountering the same issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to leave `Key` property as it is (and bindable), you can derive `KeyBinding` and add `IsEnabled` dependency property while also  overriding `Gesture`:

```
public override InputGesture Gesture
{
    get
    {
        return IsEnabled ? base.Gesture as KeyGesture : new KeyGesture(Key.None);
    }
    set
    {
        base.Gesture = value;
    }
}
// IsEnabled dependency property changed callback
private static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MyKeyBinding)?.WritePostscript(); // raise Gesture changed
}
```

dont forget to notify UI that `Gesture` changed in `IsEnabled` changed callback using `WritePostscript()` as well as to override `CreateInstanceCore`.
Usage example:

```
<utils:MyKeyBinding 
    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" 
    Key="{Binding KeyBindings.SaveKey}" 
    Modifiers="{Binding KeyBindings.SaveModifiers}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveCommandAvailable}"/>
```

Comment: I like your solution! it looks like more readable and more flexible than mine!